# Shutting down NameNode at when I tried to start the namenode service

Tags: hadoop

When I tried to `start-all.sh` namenode is not running with the log below: Please help

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 59 in class file org/mortbay/util/DateCache
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog.<clinit>(StdErrLog.java:38)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at org.mortbay.log.Log.class$(Log.java:67)
    at org.mortbay.log.Log.<clinit>(Log.java:72)
    at org.mortbay.component.Container.add(Container.java:200)
    at org.mortbay.component.Container.update(Container.java:164)
    at org.mortbay.component.Container.update(Container.java:106)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.setConnectors(Server.java:160)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.addConnector(Server.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.<init>(HttpServer.java:158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.<init>(HttpServer.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$1.run(NameNode.java:363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$1.run(NameNode.java:358)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startHttpServer(NameNode.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1217)

2014-02-21 15:13:07,336 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at DWNPCPU229/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

## UPDATE

hadoop version is `Hadoop 0.20.2-cdh3u0`
and,
java version is `java version "1.7.0_15"`
Could it be a incompatible problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right. The problem was with version incompatibility. Now I installed `Hadoop 0.20.2-cdh3u4` and it start well.